# Relative risk estimation in spatstat

Tags: spatstat

I am running into problems when computing the relative risk estimation (`relrisk.ppp`) of two point patterns: One with four marks in a rectangular region and the other with two marks in a circular region.

For the first pattern with four marks, I am able to get the relative risk and the resulting object in a `large imlist` with 4 elements corresponding to each mark.

However, for the second pattern, it gives a list of 10 elements, of which the first matrix `v` is empty with `NA` entries. I am breaking my head on what possibly could be wrong when the created point pattern objects seems to be identical. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example so we have a chance of helping you. Usually `spatstat` is perfectly capable of calculating relative risks for a point pattern observed in a circular region (really a polygon closely approximating a circle), so we need to know what is special about your data/situation.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that. How do I share the data?

Comment: Either you make a fake data example directly in R that has the same structure as your data and gives the same error or you simply post a link to the data and a few lines of code to read in the data and reproduce the error. Try hard to boil the problem down to as small an example as possible. I can recommend the `reprex` package to create this reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first dataset, the result is a list of image objects (a list of four objects of class `im`). For your second dataset, the result of `relrisk.ppp` is a single image (object of class `im`). This is the default behaviour when there are only two possible types of points (two possible mark values). See `help(relrisk.ppp)`.

In all cases, you should just be able to `plot` and `print` the resulting object. You don't need to examine the internal data of the image.

*More explanation:* when there are only two possible types of points, the default behaviour of `relrisk.ppp` is to treat them as **case-control** data, where the points belonging to the first type are treated as controls (e.g. non-infected people), and the points of the second type are treated as cases (e.g. infected people). The ratio of intensities (cases divided by controls) is estimated as an image.

**If you don't want this to happen**, set the argument `casecontrol=FALSE` and then `relrisk.ppp` will always return a list of images, with one image for each possible mark. Each image gives the spatially-varying probability of that type of point.

It's all explained in `help(relrisk.ppp)` or in the book.

Comment: Although we are able to plot and print in both cases (which worked in my case), this has implications when using downstream analysis such as `im.apply` or `eval.im`.