# Relrisk function and bandwidth selection in spatstat

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

I'm having trouble interpreting the results I got from `relrisk`. My data is a multiple point process containing two marks (two rodents species AA and RE), I want to know if they are spatially segregated or not.

```
> summary(REkm)
Marked planar point pattern:  46 points
Average intensity 0.08101444 points per square unit

*Pattern contains duplicated points*

Coordinates are given to 3 decimal places
i.e. rounded to the nearest multiple of 0.001 units

Multitype:
frequency proportion  intensity
AA        15   0.326087 0.02641775
RE        31   0.673913 0.05459669

Window: rectangle = [4, 38] x [0.3, 17] units
x 16.7 units)
Window area = 567.8 square units
```

[image: PPP]
[image: Intensity of each type]

```
relkm <- relrisk(REkm)
plot(relkm, main="Relrisk default")
```

[image: Relrisk(by default)]
The bandwidth of this `relrisk` estimation is automatically selection by default(`bw.relrisk`), but when I tried other numeric number using `sigma`= 0.5 or 1, the results are somehow kind of weird.
[image: sigma=o.5 or 1]
How did this happened? Was it because the large proportion of blank space of my ppp?

According to chapter.14 of [Spatial Point Patterns books](https://book.spatstat.org/)  and [the previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60804450/relative-risk-estimation-in-spatstat), I assume the default of `relrisk` will show the ratio of intensities (case divided by control, in my case: RE divided by AA), but if I set `casecontrol=FALSE`, I can get the spatially-varying probability of each type.
[image: Casecontrol=False]Then why the image of type RE in the `Casecontrol=False` looks exactly same as the `relrisk` estimation by default? Or they both estimate p(RE)=λRE/ λRE+λAA for each sites?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's two questions.

1. Why does the image for `RE` when `casecontrol=FALSE` look the same as the default output from `relrisk`?

The definitive source of information about `spatstat` functions is the online documentation in the help files. The help file for `relrisk.ppp` gives full details of the behaviour of this function. It says that the calculation of probabilities and risks is controlled by the argument `relative`. If `relative=FALSE` (the default), the code calculates the spatially varying probability of each type. If `relative=TRUE` it calculates the relative risk of each type `i`, defined as the ratio of the  probability of type `i` to the probability of type `c` where `c` is the type designated as the control. If you wanted the relative risk then you should set `relative=TRUE`.

2. Very different results obtained when setting `sigma=0.5` compared to the automatically selected bandwidth.

Your example output says that the window is 34 by 17 units. A smoothing bandwidth of `sigma=0.5` is very small for this region. Imagine each data point being replaced by a blurry circle of radius 0.5; there would be a lot of empty space. The smoothing procedure is encountering numerical problems which are causing the funky artefacts.

You could try a range of different values of `sigma`, say from 1 to 15, and decide which value produces the most satisfactory result.

The plot of `relrisk(REkm, casecontrol=FALSE)` suggests that the automatic bandwidth selector `bw.relriskppp` chose a much larger value of `sigma`, perhaps about 10. You can investigate this by

```
b <- bw.relriskppp(REkm)
print(b)
plot(b)
```

The print command will print the chosen value of `sigma` that was used in the default calculation. The plot command will show the cross-validation criterion which was maximised to select the bandwidth. This gives you an idea of the range of values of `sigma` that are acceptable according to the automatic selector.

Read the help file for `bw.relriskppp` about the different options available for bandwidth selection method. Maybe a different choice of method would give you a more acceptable result from your viewpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it! 
I've checked the plot of bw.relrisk and as.fv function, they showed the optimized and the range of bandwidth of my data is 4.7 and 2~8, respectively. 
About the first question, I assume images produced from default of relrisk and relative=TRUE both can show segregation if there are some regions where the ratio is high and other where it is low?